# Load a Twitter users friends list with their Twitter handles and names only?

Tags: api, rest, twitter, oauth

I would like to get the friends list of a Twitter user with only the Twitter handles (@screen_name) and their names. Is that possible?
Currently the API endpoint of https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list returns also such things as profile_image, statuses_count and so on.
(My goal is to load as less data as possible from Twitters API)

Comment: Why do you want to load less data?

Comment: Because it's faster to load a few names than tons of additional data I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

The data is all gzipped - so you'll only be saving a few bytes.  But, if that's really what you want to do, you can add the following parameters.

`skip_status=true`

`include_user_entities=false`

It won't strip out everything, but it will reduce the total transfer size.

Comment: Thank you. What data represents `include_user_entities`? Is it for the user profile image path and bio?

Comment: Try it and find out :-)

Comment: Did that but I don't see a difference - it's the same data as before.